# How to pick the elements that are in the same position in two sublists of a list

Tags: python, list

There are a list containing two sublists shown below:

```
A = [[1,26,34,67,100],[12,15,27,20,34]]
```

The element in the first sublist represents the variable's index,while it in the second sublist represents the variable's corresponding value.
My question is that how can I pick the elements at the same position in two sublists at the same time?

I tried in this way:

```
for x,y in A:
    index = A[0][x]
    value= A[1][y]
```

But it didn't work (I am new to python code..). Could you please me a clue about how to get the solution of my question?

Comment: You're probably looking for: `list(zip(*A))`

Comment: sounds like a dict

Comment: `for index, value in zip(*A):`